# Internal volts in arduino for percent battery

Tags: voltage-level, battery

I'm working on a small project that is creating me a headache. I know arduimo (ATmega 328P .... etc. ..) has an internal voltage source code millivolts, but I would like to know how the full source code become percentage where 3 volts = 0%  and 4.2 volts = % 100% ??? . I appreciate the help because in codes is not my forte. I leave the code so Help me complete. Thank you.

```
long readVcc() {
  long result;
  // Read 1.1V reference against AVcc
  ADMUX = _BV(REFS0) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2) | _BV(MUX1);
  delay(2); // Wait for Vref to settle
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC); // Convert
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA,ADSC));
  result = ADCL;
  result |= ADCH<<8;
  result = 1126400L / result; // Back-calculate AVcc in mV
  return result;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println( readVcc(), DEC );
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about the calculation X = (V - 3)* 100/(4.2 - 3) where V is the voltage (in volts) and X is the percentage?  When V = 3 this gives X = 0, when V = 4.2 this gives X = 100

Comment: @jim readVCC() returns a voltage in mV, so adjust for that and add as a answer :D

Comment: Mind you that the band gap reference is reasonably stable over time, but its absolute value in not very accurate. You may want to 'calibrate' the returned result from your readVcc function.

Comment: The charge on my arduino and something I'm doing wrong it gives me error :-(

Comment: Where did the code you posted come from? That's some pretty cryptic code.

Comment: "3 volts = 0% and 4.2 volts = % 100%" This sounds a lot like you are dealing with a battery, probably lithium of sorts, and you should be aware that battery remaining charge has some very non-linear regions. You will need something more complicated - a higher order equation, multiple regions, or a lookup table and interpolation.

Comment: Hello Duncan C sorry for replying so late but my job car electronics I removed my long wire-level and breakdowns but not at the programming level (low level) and I'm trying to develop a car burglar alarm so I need help . The source code I've taken from this website .  https://code.google.com/p/tinkerit/wiki/SecretVoltmeter

Comment: Hello Chris Stratton, if it comes to lipo batteries and discharge curve I got from this website: https://learn.adafruit.com/li-ion-and-lipoly-batteries/voltages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map()`](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/map)

```
unsigned char level = map(readVcc(), 3000, 4200, 0, 100);
```

Comment: You need to find a C language tutorial ***very badly***, because you have *no* clue what you're doing, and you're not doing yourself or anyone else any favors like this.

Comment: sorry did not mean to, I just needed help, so asked.Thanks anyway

Comment: I do not in any way mind answering questions. The thing is that the fundamentals required to understand my answer are missing. Please take some time to familiarize yourself with C language structures.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I agree with your comment about needing a grounding in C. However, your answer uses the map function, which is part of the Arduino libraries, not straight C.

Comment: @DuncanC: Sure, but understanding how functions and function calls work and interrelate is.

Comment: Any idea why there's no comment button on the original question? I want to see if the code is the OPs or somebody else's.

Comment: @DuncanC: I'm almost certain it's not theirs.